# Esconder sidebar al hacer click en el menu

Tags: jquery

Tengo un sidebar colapsable y quiero al hacer click en un menu o submenu, que se abra la pantalla correspondiente pero que se esconda el sidebar.

El codigo html del sidebar es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">

        <div id="dismiss">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>MENU PRINCIPAL</h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <ul >
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" href="" >
             <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i><span  id="art"> ARTICULO - F2</span>
        </a>
            </ul>
                <ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <ul >
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" href="" >
            <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i><span  id="art"> SERVICIO - F4</span>
        </a>
            </ul>
                <ul>  
demas codigo del menu
```

Probe acceder a la clase list-unstyled components para lo mismo pero nada:

```js
   $('.list-unstyled components ul li').on('click', function () {

            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        
        });
```

¿Como podria hacerlo?